# I am not getting the output for this script

Tags: php, mysql

i have written a code but that is not working. below is a code which enters an image into the database on user input. But my problem is that when i am calling it to print on page, nothing is diaplaying, please help me here.

```
<?php
$conx=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sultan','colour');
$sql = "SELECT theme from  colors WHERE username='shail' ";
$sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($sqli);
$theme=$row[0];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$theme=$_POST['theme'];
$sql = "UPDATE colors SET theme='$theme' WHERE username='shail' ";
$sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);

}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{ background-image:url(<?php echo $theme  ?>) ;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
Input your picture<input type="file" name="theme" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you doing the first `SELECT` query if you're just going to overwrite the variable `$theme` with `$_POST['theme']` later?

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if the script is getting an error. That would explain the blank page you're getting.

Comment: I am using select because in case user dont want to change the theme, the old one should be displayed. php is not showing any error

Comment: You should do that in the `else` part of the `if`, since there's no need to do the `SELECT` if they're changing it.

Comment: i made the changes but still no output

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with the question, they were just a recommendation for better coding.

Comment: Image path is not correct

Comment: What's the output of `$theme`?

Comment: That form cannot submit a file because there is no `enctype=multipart/form-data` property in your `<form>` tag

Comment: @RaymondAtivie That, and the file isn't saved the begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate the statement.

current

```
<?php echo $theme  ?>
```

new

```
<?php echo $theme;  ?>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't mind leaving out the semicolon before `?>`.

Comment: Didn't noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out. I've had bad experience with not terminating statements.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$conx=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','colour');
$sql = "SELECT theme from  colors WHERE username='shail' ";
$sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($sqli);
$theme=$row[0];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        // new code
        $path = '/';
        $fileName = $_FILES['theme']["name"]; 
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES['theme']["tmp_name"];
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['theme']["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $temp = explode('.', $fileName );
        $ext = array_pop($temp );
        $name = implode('.', $temp );
        $FileNM = $name.time().".".$extension;
        $theme = $FileNM.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theme']["tmp_name"], $theme);

        $sql = "UPDATE colors SET theme='$theme' WHERE username='shail' ";
        $sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    body{ background-image:url(<?php echo $theme;  ?>) ;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Input your picture<input type="file" name="theme" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and yes you need to change database coinfig on top of file

Comment: Good answer @Chetan. But I guess it is better if you can briefly explain the newly added code + the mistake he has done earlier as well.

Comment: @Chetan- Its working man. Thanks for solving my problem Now as your code suggest that it is saving the file in dirctory. so is it possible to upload that file from directory to webpage again.. see what i means. you have changed your theme to theme1 and it gets stored. Next time you changed it to theme2. On third login you want to select theme1 from directory not from your computer. is it possible?

Comment: @user3750945 : was it the statement termination which caused you no output?

Comment: it was not termination, i changed the position but nothing was displayed. i used chetan's script that works

Comment: hi Rumesh Eranga it's possible you want..!, now files stored in directory, and that file name stored in database

Comment: chetan,how can i call back the stores image from directory to page.

Comment: i changed path to         $path = "..img/";
.. but nothing is getting stored in it.. :(..  how can i check the size of pload and display the error if it is more than 1mb. is it possible to check the ext of a file and allow only jpg to uoload>

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$conx=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','colour');
$sql = "SELECT theme from  colors WHERE username='shail' ";
$sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($sqli);
$theme=$row[0];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        // new code
        $error1="";
        $error2="";
        if ($_FILES["theme"]["type"] !== "image/jpeg"){
            echo $error1 = "File is not in JPG!";
        }else{
            $error1="";
        }

        if(($_FILES["theme"]["size"] > 1024)){
            echo $error2 = "File size not allowed more than 1 MB!";
        }else{
            $error2="";
        }

        if($error1 =="" && $error2==""){
            $fileName = $_FILES['theme']["name"]; 
            $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES['theme']["tmp_name"];
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['theme']["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            $temp = explode('.', $fileName );
            $ext = array_pop($temp );
            $name = implode('.', $temp );
            $FileNM = $name.time().".".$extension;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theme']["tmp_name"], "img/".$FileNM);

            $sql = "UPDATE colors SET theme='$FileNM' WHERE username='shail' ";
            $sqli=mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
        }

}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    body{ background-image:url(<?php echo "img/".$FileNM;  ?>) ;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Input your picture<input type="file" name="theme" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this but still a question remaining.. why the files are not getting stored in the folder i want inside the directory..?

Comment: i have already created it. what would be path root for it. i am using ../img/

Comment: 1. move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theme']["tmp_name"], "../img/".$FileNM);

Comment: 2. body{ background-image:url(<?php echo "../img/".$FileNM;  ?>) ;}

Comment: ok thanks. Today experimenting with the above script, i encountered one more problem. at the time of account creation, by default he gets a light blue theme. Now i am wondering what should i do to get that back on users wish if he don't like his manually set theme.